# domain name vs ip address, same server, but different speed

Tags: dns, performance, ip-address, vps

I have two similar sites:
- two of them have almost exactly the same codes, and running on the same server
- both sites are the same, they just use different language.
- database of the slower site is populated (maybe only the user table) the other tables for site content is the same
- the faster uses root to access database

one of the sites is not released yet, so it uses IP Address to access the site instead of domain name

the site that is using IP address is faster (lot faster)
the site that is using domain name is slower

do you know why is this happening what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolver should only have to run once per FQDN, so you might see a difference during the first access, but shouldn't incur that overhead for accesses after that.